# how to convert dynamically created character array into integer array when the input is integers delimited with space

Tags: c, integer, character, type-conversion, dynamic-arrays

I want to create two arrays, one is a character array and the second is an integer array. Both are created dynamically when user provides input about the number of integers element. All the integers are delimited by spaces.

Input:

First line consists of `N`, Here `N` is number of integers. Say user inputs 5, the next line will contain `N` integers delimited by space. i.e 5 integers `5 10 23 456 2`

Output:

Output will show the elements from the integer array i.e `int_array[i], int_array[i+1]`.... `5,10` ...

But when I tried with my code, I can see only 0's from integer array.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *cstois(char *char_array, int *int_array, int n) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (char_array[i] >= '0' && char_array[i] <= '9') {
            int_array[j] == int_array[j] * 10 + (char_array[i] - '0');
        } else
        if (char_array[i] == ' ') {
            j++;
        } else
           continue;
    }
    return int_array;
}

int main() {
    int i, n;
    printf("enter no. of elements");
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    char *char_array;
    char_array = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    fgets(char_array, sizeof(char_array), stdin);
    int *int_array = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    cstois(&char_array[0], &int_array[0], n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", int_array[i]);
    free(char_array);
    free(int_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you have a file containing integers, why read them as text to begin with? Why not use e.g. `fscanf` in a loop?

Comment: `int_array[j]==int_array[j] * ...`  ?? comparison not intended ? Oh copy/paste, ye are a ruthless wench. After you fix that, you'll find it still doesn't work, since `var = var * anything` will never amount to much when `var` is initially zero (which it is after your `calloc`). That's just a design flaw needing attention.

Comment: sorry that is a single '=' i mistyped it.

Comment: How one mistypes *anything* when copy/pasting code sections into a question, I never understand. Regardless, see the second part of my comment. And another design flaw. You had better hope no string of digits forming your integers is longer than three characters, or you have a buffer-overflow in the making., assuming you fix `fgets(char_array,sizeof(char_array),stdin);`, which is also wrong. Likewise, hope there is never more than a single whitespace char separating each cluster of digits, etc. Lots to think about. Personally, I'd just use the scanf family like Joachim suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- There is no standard header `<malloc.h>`.  `malloc()` is defined in `<stdlib.h>`.
- in function `cstois()`, you do not correctly update the number because of a typo: `int_array[j] == int_array[j] * 10 + (char_array[i] - '0');` should be `int_array[j] = int_array[j] * 10 + (char_array[i] - '0');`
- You ignore all characters that are not digits nor the space character.  This is not necessarily correct: `1,2,3` would be parsed as `123` instead of being reported as an error.
- Much worse even, you do not check for `'\0'` when scanning the input buffer.  If there are not enough numbers in the line read from the user, you scan beynd the end of the string and potentially beyond the end of the array, invoking undefined behavior.
- You skip to the next element upon the space character. Separating numbers with multiple spaces would cause numbers to be skipped incorrectly.
- You cannot handle negative numbers.
- in function `main()`, the input array is allocated as `char_array = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));`.  This is incorrect as it limits the average number of digits to 3 for 32 bit ints... You should allocate at least 20 digits per number to allow for large integers.
- The line read from the user with `fgets()` is tragically short: `sizeof(char_array)` is the size of the pointer, not the size allocated for the array.  Save that size to a variable and pass it to both `malloc()` and `fgets()`.
- You do not check the return value of `scanf()`, nor that of `fgets()` or `malloc()`.  An empty file will not be handled correctly.

An easy way to handle multiple space separators and negative numbers is to use `strtol()`:

```
int *cstois(char *char_array, int *int_array, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int_array[i] = strtol(char_array, &char_array, 10);
    }
    return int_array;
}
```

This simplistic implementation will stop at the first non-number and fill all remaining entries in `int_array` with `0`.  Missing numbers will similarly yield zero values in the array.

Comment: thank you very much charlie, i'm gonna try to solve all such problems you showed me here.

Comment: thanx charlie again, i have done the programme and i am going to optimize it to handle multiple spaces and negative values too.

Answer (score 0):

i printed the string after taking input, and i saw there is values till no space occurs. i s there any modification hat i should make with fgets. Here is the modified code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *cstois(char *char_array, int *int_array, int n) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (char_array[i] >= '0' && char_array[i] <= '9') {
            int_array[j] = (int_array[j] * 10) + (char_array[i] - '0');
        } else
        if (char_array[i] == ' ') {
            if (i == 0)
                continue;
            else
                j++;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return int_array;
}

int main() {
    int i, n, length_of_char;
    printf("enter no. of elements");
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    char *char_array;
    char_array = (char*)malloc(n * 5);
    fgets(char_array, sizeof(char_array), stdin);
    printf("%s\n", char_array);
    length_of_char = strlen(char_array);
    printf("%d\n", length_of_char);
    int *int_array = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    cstois(&char_array[0], &int_array[0], length_of_char);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d\n", int_array[i]);
    free(char_array);
    free(int_array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your test `if(i==0)  continue;` only works if the very first character is a space.  Look at my edit, learn to indent and space your code to make it easier to read.  `fgets()` still only reads 3 bytes or so... use the length of the array, not `sizeof(char_array);`.